# battleships but cannot be defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been making a GUI for a battleships game but when the code is run I get the error:

A1.configure(relief=SUNKEN)

NameError: name 'A1' is not defined

i realized that the buttons were named inside a `def` function so i made them `global` however the same error still comes up. however i am very new to `global` and am not entirely sure that i used it right.

```
from tkinter import*
import random
import time

##### main
window = Tk()
window.title("battleships")

# makes every button global
global A1
global A2
global A3
global B1
global B2
global B3
global C1
global C2
global C3

# command that places the buttons when the ships are placed
def placeships():
    A1 = Button(window, width=5, height=2, text="A1", command=clickA1).place(x=0, y=0)
    A2 = Button(window, width=5, height=2, text="A2", command=clickA2).place(x=50, y=0)
    A3 = Button(window, width=5, height=2, text="A3", command=clickA3).place(x=100, y=0)
    B1 = Button(window, width=5, height=2, text="B1", command=clickB1).place(x=0, y=50)
    B2 = Button(window, width=5, height=2, text="B2", command=clickB2).place(x=50, y=50)
    B3 = Button(window, width=5, height=2, text="B3", command=clickB3).place(x=100, y=50)
    C1 = Button(window, width=5, height=2, text="C1", command=clickC1).place(x=0, y=100)
    C2 = Button(window, width=5, height=2, text="C2", command=clickC2).place(x=50, y=100)
    C3 = Button(window, width=5, height=2, text="C3", command=clickC3).place(x=100, y=100)

# commands for the buttons
def clickA1():
    A1.configure(relief=SUNKEN)
def clickA2():
    A2.configure(relief=SUNKEN)
def clickA3():
    A3.configure(relief=SUNKEN)
def clickB1():
    B1.configure(relief=SUNKEN)
def clickB2():
    B2.configure(relief=SUNKEN)
def clickB3():
    B3.configure(relief=SUNKEN)
def clickC1():
    C1.configure(relief=SUNKEN)
def clickC2():
    C2.configure(relief=SUNKEN)
def clickC3():
    C3.configure(relief=SUNKEN)

placeships()
```

have i used `global` correctly and if so why does the error occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using `global` correct. You must declare them as global inside the function:

```
def placeships():
    global A1, A2, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`global` changes the scope of a local name to a global name. As such, it has to go in the scope where the name is being assigned to, not the global scope itself.

```
def placeships():
    global A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3
    A1 = Button(window, width=5, height=2, text="A1", command=clickA1).place(x=0, y=0)
    A2 = Button(window, width=5, height=2, text="A2", command=clickA2).place(x=50, y=0)
    A3 = Button(window, width=5, height=2, text="A3", command=clickA3).place(x=100, y=0)
    B1 = Button(window, width=5, height=2, text="B1", command=clickB1).place(x=0, y=50)
    B2 = Button(window, width=5, height=2, text="B2", command=clickB2).place(x=50, y=50)
    B3 = Button(window, width=5, height=2, text="B3", command=clickB3).place(x=100, y=50)
    C1 = Button(window, width=5, height=2, text="C1", command=clickC1).place(x=0, y=100)
    C2 = Button(window, width=5, height=2, text="C2", command=clickC2).place(x=50, y=100)
    C3 = Button(window, width=5, height=2, text="C3", command=clickC3).place(x=100, y=100)
```